# how to block the textbox and button from moving

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my html source to put the textbox and the submit button in my webpage.

When a user move the size on the browser, it will move the textbox and the button to the left side which it supposed to stay in the middle without get moving to the left or right.

I want to block the textbox and the button from moving to the left or right.

Here is what it supposed to be like:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/52mmiq.jpg

When I move the size of the browser, it will show like this:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/2z685tx.jpg

Here is where the problem is:

```
<div id="WFItem5736404" class="wf-formTpl">
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html?u=KLlP" method="post">
            <div id="WFIcenter" class="wf-body">
                        <div class="wf-contbox">
                            <div class="wf-inputpos">
                                <input name="email" class="Email" style="position: absolute; left: 264px; top: 520px; width: 423px; height: 51px;" type="text" data-placeholder="yes" placeholder="Enter your Email Address...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wf-contbox">
                            <div class="wf-inputpos">
                                <input name="submit" class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 264px; top: 576px; width: 434px; height: 56px;" type="image" src="button.png">
```

Here is the html source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Blogging to Financial Freedom | Empower Network</title>
<meta name="description" content="Empower Network's a truly system that will empower you and every member really has your back! I look forward to grow with it and help others empower themselves!">
<meta name="keywords" content="Empower Network, empower network products, tracey walker empower network, empower network banners, dave sharpe empower network, david wood empower network scam, empower network income disclosure,">

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(ontheroad.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#000000;  
}

#MainContent {
    height: 598px;
    width: 466px;
    background-image: url(content.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 99px;
}
#MainContent #content {
    height: 315px;
}
#MainContent #form {
    height: 142px;
    text-align: center;
}
#MainContent #form form {
    height: 138px;
    width: 334px;
}
.Email  {
    height: 37px;
    width: 259px;
    border: 3px solid #efba2e;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.button {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>


<script src="../../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="MainContent">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="form">
  <div id="WFItem5736404" class="wf-formTpl">
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html?u=KLlP" method="post">
            <div id="WFIcenter" class="wf-body">
                        <div class="wf-contbox">
                            <div class="wf-inputpos">
                                <input name="email" class="Email" style="position: absolute; left: 264px; top: 520px; width: 423px; height: 51px;" type="text" data-placeholder="yes" placeholder="Enter your Email Address...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wf-contbox">
                            <div class="wf-inputpos">
                                <input name="submit" class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 264px; top: 576px; width: 434px; height: 56px;" type="image" src="button.png">
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="webform_id" value="5736404" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=5736404&mg_param1=1&u=KLlP"></script>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "email");
</script>


<div data-lead-id="footer-id" id="footer">
<p class="legal leadstyle-text" style="position: absolute; left: 437px; top: 688px; display: block;">Legal Information</p>

<p class="note" data-lead-id="note-id">

<img alt="privacy" class="leadstyle-image" src="locked.png" style="position: absolute; left: 320px; top: 721px; max-width: 32px; display: inline;">

<div id="leadstyle-text" style="position: absolute; left: 251px; top: 732px; width: 603px; height: 16px; text-align: center;">

<span class="sourcesanspro90FFFFFFt">Your Information is 100% Secure and Will Never Be Shared With Anyone.</span><span class="sourcesanspro100FFFFFFt"> </span></div>

<div id="bottom-div" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 644px; width: 20px; height: 120px;">




</body>
</html>
```

Can you please tell me how i can block the textbox and the button from moving to the left and right?

Comment: You are defining specific widths, so those input fields will always be that size. I would suggest you use max-width when styling your forms, or using width percentages. ex max-width: 200px or width: 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have your two input fields as `position: absolute`, which is fine but it means that they are positioned 264px to the left and 520px from the top of your *page* and not from the box around your form, which is what you want.

Put a `position: relative;` property on `#MainContent` in your CSS.

```
#MainContent {
  position: relative; /* Add this line */
  height: 598px;
  width: 466px;
  background-image: url(content.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 99px;
}
```

Then position your two form fields from the bottom of the surrounding box. I can't replicate your code exactly so this will be a guess:

**Email Field:**

`<input name="email" class="Email" style="position: absolute; left: 2%; bottom: 80px; width: 96%; height: 51px;" type="text" data-placeholder="yes" placeholder="Enter your Email Address...">`

**Submit Button**

`<input name="submit" class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 2%; bottom: 20px; width: 96%; height: 56px;" type="image" src="button.png">`

I changed the width of these boxes to be 96% of the surrounding box pushed from the left by 2%, leaving an equal 2% on the right hand side, which should keep your form fields centered. You may need to alter the `bottom` values to recreate the spacing you had before.